# Enhanced SR SOP Class"1.2.840.10008.5.1.4.1.1.88.22" Is useful to draw Region of Interest

Tags: dicom

```
SOP Class UID :- "1.2.840.10008.5.1.4.1.1.88.22" of Enhanced SR SOP Class Name
```

In this SR Modality having various dicom tags from these various tag I want to draw the **"Region of Interest"(ROI)** on the MR Modality.

this is my SR Dicom file [SR DICOM](http://www.uploadmb.com/dw.php?id=1365402449)

So help me to know which SR Modality Tag I use to draw the marker on MR Modality or which referential tag I use to get ROI and MR reference SOP Instance UID with respect to SR Modality

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have been doing a large amount of work with mammography SR recently. I found [David Clunie's book](http://www.pixelmed.com/srbook.html) to be excellent. You can find more info on his site and a link to the book.

I tried to have a look at your file but I can't access it so I will tell you about my experience of SR in mammography.

To tackle the SR in mammography I wrote a tool that is now part of PyDICOM to understand the structure of the SR files. I'm sure there are similar tools in other languages. Below is a screen capture of an example.

The information about the ROI is stored in the SCOORD content item. Change this to change the ROI. I have found different types of SCOORD items such as `centre` and `outline` so you would need to be consistent in changing them. The one I have highlighted is an outline of a ROI.

[image]

If you notice the reference content identifier on the SCOORD has the value [1,2,1]. This means you go to the root (1) go to the second item (2) and then the first item in the referenced Series Sequence (1). The ReferencedSOPInstanceUID in there is the image on which the SCOORD is drawn.

[image]

**EDIT 1**

I had a look at your file but I can't find and SCOORD content items. Also there are no ReferencedSOPInstances.

Comment: I trying to search above tag into attach SR Dicom file, but it  has no such kind of tag as you mention so its not work